# Kotlin MapView Library to Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to implement this Kotlin library [MapView](https://github.com/peterLaurence/MapView) to my Android Studio project based on Java.
I'm a beginner and I only have some knowledge of Java, so I tried to decompile MapView's demo project and convert the part I needed to Java with Kotlin plugin, but the result wasn't working and now I'm back to zero.
On MapView's documentation there is a snippet on how to set up a MapView:

```
val mapView = MapView(context)
val tileStreamProvider = object : TileStreamProvider {
   override fun getTileStream(row: Int, col: Int, zoomLvl: Int): InputStream? {
     return FileInputStream(File("path/{zoomLvl}/{row}/{col}.jpg")) // or it can be a remote HTTP fetch
   }
}

val config = MapViewConfiguration(levelCount = 7, fullWidth = 25000, fullHeight = 12500,
                                  tileSize = 256, tileStreamProvider = tileStreamProvider)
                                  .setMaxScale(2f)

/* Configuration */
mapView.configure(config)
```

I have set up the library on my project already but I don't know how to convert that snippet to Java and then show the MapView in a new Empty Activity.

Is it something possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    MapView mapView = new MapView(context);
    
    MapViewConfiguration mapViewConfiguration = new MapViewConfiguration(7, 25000, 12500, 256, new TileStreamProvider() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public InputStream getTileStream(int i, int i1, int i2) {
            try {
                return new FileInputStream(new File("path/{zoomLvl}/{row}/{col}.jpg")); // or it can be a remote HTTP fetch
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // handle error
                return null;
            }
        }
    }).setMaxScale(2f);

    mapView.configure(mapViewConfiguration);
```

I converted the snippet to Java for you, but I suggest you view the code and try to learn from it, so in the future you can easily do it on your own.

Please specifically note that:

1. There are no named arguments (function parameters) in Java.
2. The syntax to create an anonymous class is different (no `object` in Java)
3. Objects instances are created with the keyword `new`
4. You must handle Exceptions with try/catch